# Matching using a date range

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a table of cases and a table of controls. I want to create a matched set of controls using exact matching on age and sex. I also want to specify that the control has at least one year of data before the case's date of death (`dod`).

The data look like this:

```
nControls <- 10e4
nCases <- 10e2
start_date <- as.Date('2011-04-01')
end_date <- as.Date('2016-04-01')

ages <- paste0(seq(0, 75, 5), '-', seq(4, 79, 5))
nAges <- length(ages)

controls <- data.frame(
  id = seq_len(nControls),
  start = sample(seq(start_date, end_date, by = 'year'), size = nControls, replace = T),
  dur = sample(1:5, nControls, replace = T) * 365.25,
  age = sample(ages, nControls, replace = T, prob = 1:nAges / sum(1:nAges)),
  sex = sample(c('m', 'f'), nControls, replace = T, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)))
controls$end <- controls$start + controls$dur

cases <- data.frame(
  id = seq_len(nCases),
  dod = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/04/01'), as.Date('2016/04/01'), by = 'day'), size = nCases, replace = T),
  age = sample(ages, nCases, replace = T),
  sex = sample(c('m', 'f'), nCases, replace = T))
```

Matching on age and sex alone is easily done, either manually or with the `MatchIt` package:

```
controls$treat <- 0
cases$treat <- 1
mt <- rbind(controls[,c('treat', 'age', 'sex')], cases[,c('treat', 'age', 'sex')])
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ age + sex, data = mt, exact = c('age', 'sex'), method = 'nearest', ratio = 2)
```

But I can't figure out how to include the criteria that `cases$dod` should be before `controls$end` and at least 1 year after `controls$start`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after (desired output is missing).. but here's a first go:

The code below performes a `data.table` left non-equi join on `sex` and `age` from cases and controls, where `start.control < dod - 1 year` and `end.control > dod`:

**code**

```
library( data.table )
library( lubridate )

#create data.tables
dt.controls <- as.data.table( controls )  #or use setDT()
dt.cases <- as.data.table( cases )  #or use setDT()
#add suffixes, to identify the columns after join
names( dt.controls ) <- paste0( names( dt.controls ), ".control" )
names( dt.cases ) <- paste0( names( dt.cases ), ".case" )
#save colum order for later use
colorder <- c( names( dt.cases), names( dt.controls ) )
#set join columns
dt.controls[, `:=`( age.join = age.control, 
                    sex.join = sex.control, 
                    start.join = start.control, 
                    end.join = end.control)]

dt.cases[, `:=`( age.join = age.case, 
                 sex.join = sex.case, 
                 dod.join.start = dod.case %m-% lubridate::years( 1 ),  #!! %m-%
                 dod.join.end = dod.case )]  
#perform non-equi join
result <- dt.controls[ dt.cases, on = .( age.join , 
                                         sex.join, 
                                         start.join < dod.join.start, 
                                         end.join > dod.join.end ), 
                       mult = "first", 
                       nomatch = NA ]
#drop the *.join columns
result[, grep( ".join$", names( result ) ) := NULL]
#set column order so cases come first, controls after
setcolorder( result, colorder )
```

**output**

```
head(result)
#    id.case   dod.case age.case sex.case id.control start.control dur.control age.control sex.control end.control
# 1:       1 2012-12-26      5-9        m        318    2011-04-01     1826.25         5-9           m  2016-03-31
# 2:       2 2015-09-19    75-79        f         26    2012-04-01     1461.00       75-79           f  2016-04-01
# 3:       3 2011-08-17    25-29        m         NA          <NA>          NA        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
# 4:       4 2011-07-23    35-39        f         NA          <NA>          NA        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
# 5:       5 2013-11-16    30-34        f        112    2012-04-01      730.50       30-34           f  2014-04-01
# 6:       6 2014-09-17      5-9        f        784    2013-04-01     1826.25         5-9           f  2018-04-01
```

You can filldle with the `nomatch` and the `mult`-arguments of the join to 'tweak' the output...

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm still working through this but I guess it gives 1:1 matching of cases to controls?

Comment: Yes, it does. If you want one-to-all matches, set  mult=“all”.